# sap.ui.unified controls in UI Theme Designer

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform, sapui5

I am trying to create a custom theme for my SAPUI5 application.

I have a **trial** HCP account and I am using the the trial subscription for theme designer. But when I open up a new theme to create, I don't see any `sap.m`, `sap.viz`, `sap.ui.unified` controls.

Is this a limitation to the trial account?
Is there a different way to enable or activate the "m" library controls?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No limitation there. You just need to use the right demo applications resp. test suites that contain `sap.m`, `sap.viz` or `sap.unified` controls.

On the very left of 'Theme Designer' you can add 'Target Pages'. Just use one of the Test Suites shown in the middle area, e.g. use 'SAPUI5 Application Previews' and check 'Explored' which will bring you the well-known 'Explored' app in the preview area. It contains most of the controls you are looking for.

In case you are missing anything you can always preview your own application ('Target Pages' > 'Application') the be able to style all the desired controls.